# how to run odoo 11 by exec odoo11 container

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I have created a container of odoo11 that contain postgres (i don't use postgres as docker image ), but when i try to run command of odoo [ sudo docker exec -it pgodoo /bin/bash ], i have this exception:

```
root@84b713283406:/opt/odoo11# ls
extra-addons  odoo  wkhtmltopdf_0.12.1-2_amd64.deb
root@84b713283406:/opt/odoo11# /opt/odoo11/ 
extra-addons/ odoo/         
root@84b713283406:/opt/odoo11# /opt/odoo11/odoo/odoo-bin 
Running as user 'root' is a security risk.
2018-11-29 18:12:12,289 70 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 11.0
2018-11-29 18:12:12,289 70 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/root/.local/share/Odoo/addons/11.0', '/opt/odoo11/odoo/odoo/addons', '/opt/odoo11/odoo/addons']
2018-11-29 18:12:12,290 70 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default
Exception in thread odoo.service.httpd:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 261, in http_thread
    self.httpd = ThreadedWSGIServerReloadable(self.interface, self.port, app)
  File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 111, in __init__
    handler=RequestHandler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 476, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 121, in server_bind
    super(ThreadedWSGIServerReloadable, self).server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

2018-11-29 18:12:12,416 70 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: What part of the exception is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The address is already in use so you already have Odoo running in your container. You did not specify more information about the container you are running so we do not know your exact setup. I assume you do not need to run odoo second time but it should be accessible from the port you have specified. This is by default port 8069, so opening http://localhost:8069 should bring Odoo to your browser.

If you still need to run odoo-bin e.g. for scaffolding, you can specify a different port with command line parameter --http-port . More info on command line parameters can be found here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/cmdline.html

```
$ /opt/odoo11/odoo/odoo-bin --http-port 8169
```

This starts Odoo so that it is available in local address http://localhost:8169.

Please consider your setup as an anti-pattern for containerized applications because:

1. manually starting applications in containers. Everything should be done in container definition code.
2. putting multiple things in same container. You should separate postgres and odoo in different containers.

You can find more information about how to run Odoo in Docker in a containerized way from Unkkuri's blog post [Odoo 12 in Docker Container](https://unkkuri.com/blog/unkkuri-blog-1/post/odoo-12-in-docker-container-25) or [Install Odoo version 11 in Docker Container](https://unkkuri.com/blog/unkkuri-blog-1/post/install-odoo-version-11-in-docker-container-21).

Comment: thank you, but i need not  separate postgres and odoo in different containers.
i want to run a single image that will run both postgres and odoo

Comment: Yes, that is totally fine and doable, even though it is not best practice in containers. With the —http-port parameter you are able to overcome the ”Address already in use” error and execute odoo process.